# XSLT-1.0 how to eliminate redundancy, but selecting one particular node instead of the first

Tags: xslt, sorting, grouping, xslt-1.0, max

I have this XML

```
<data>
    <peptides>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
            <score>4000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
            <score>6000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>1000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>8000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>222</accession>
            <sequence>CCC</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>222</accession>
            <sequence>CCC</sequence>
            <score>9000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>222</accession>
            <sequence>CCC</sequence>
            <score>2000</score>
        </peptide>
  </peptides>
</data>
```

With the following XSLT, I can get the peptides with ´accession´ "111", eliminating the redundancy of sequences. So that I get this XML

```
<root>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        <score>4000</score>
    </peptide>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>BBB</sequence>
        <score>5000</score>
    </peptide>
</root>
```

Here it is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byAcc"    match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="accession" />
    <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byAcc','111')
            [
            generate-id()
            =
            generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])
            ]">
            <xsl:sort select="sequence" data-type="text"/>
            <xsl:sort select="score" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the live example [here](http://xsltcake.com/slices/lH3JVa)

Then, the problem is that from all the redundancy, the "selected" node is just the first that appears in the original XML.

I need to select, of all the redundant peptides (i.e., those with the same accession and sequence), the one with maximum score.

The wished XML would be this one then

```
<root>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        <score>6000</score>
    </peptide>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>BBB</sequence>
        <score>8000</score>
    </peptide>
</root>
```

If it is not clear, please let me know and I will re-edit the question. Thanks a lot.

Gerard

Comment: It is clear, but only because I answered your previous question. Please, always provide the simplest and shortest possible example, like the one in the answer to your previous question. In this particular case, the XML is too long and the reader has to guess what the XSLT code is doing. You could have said: "We are grouping on two keys and sorting by `score`. However I need not the first representative from each group but the one with maximum score". There still remains some potential ambiguity, because there might be more than one elements in a group that have the same, maximum `score`.

Comment: I am getting better in recognizing and simplifying the problems that I have, so there is hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="byAcc"    match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="accession" />
 <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "key('byAcc','111')
            [
            generate-id()
            =
            generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])
            ]">
    <xsl:sort select="sequence" data-type="text"/>
    <xsl:sort select="score" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide">
    <xsl:for-each select=
    "key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))">
      <xsl:sort select="score" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <peptides>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
            <score>4000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
            <score>6000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>1000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>8000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>222</accession>
            <sequence>CCC</sequence>
            <score>5000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>222</accession>
            <sequence>CCC</sequence>
            <score>9000</score>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>222</accession>
            <sequence>CCC</sequence>
            <score>2000</score>
        </peptide>
  </peptides>
</data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <peptide>
      <accession>111</accession>
      <sequence>AAA</sequence>
      <score>6000</score>
   </peptide>
   <peptide>
      <accession>111</accession>
      <sequence>BBB</sequence>
      <score>8000</score>
   </peptide>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The template that processes every first element from a group, gets all the elements in the current group (using the `key()` function).
2. Then it uses a code snippet to find the ones of all these that have a maximum `score`. Only the first such element is output.

Comment: Yes, it works as I needed. As I understand, the trick is to send the "apply-template" only once, but then once in the template select again all the nodes, sort them and select only the first one. Thanks!